# CosmosDB Gremlin - filter nodes that don't have a particular type of edge

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

In a CosmosDB Graph collection, I'm trying to find all nodes of type `typeA` that do **not** have any "live" edges pointing to nodes of type `typeB`.

Some edges may be "soft-deleted" (i.e. `g.E().has('softDeleted', true)` ). These edges should be ignored.

This is what I tried:

```
g.V().hasLabel('typeA')
-> returns 10 nodes of type "typeA", as expected

g.V().hasLabel('typeA')
     .outE().not(has('softDelete', true))
     .inV().hasLabel('typeB')
-> returns 2 nodes of type "typeB", as expected

g.V().hasLabel('typeA')
     .where( // same condition as above, inside a 'where' clause
         outE().not(has('softDelete', true))
         .inV().hasLabel('typeB')
         .count().is(eq(0))   // " where there are no such edges"
     )
-> returns all 10 nodes of type "typeA" again ?!
```

In the query above, applying the `where` clause seems to not filter anything.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will find all `typeA` vertices that do not have an edge to a `typeB` vertex. Only edges that have no `softDelete` property or that edges that have `softDelete` set to `false` will be considered, other edges will be ignored.

```
g.V().hasLabel('typeA').
  not(outE().or(hasNot('softDelete'),
                has   ('softDelete', false)).
        inV().hasLabel('typeB'))
```